How to Extend and Override the Mastodon Frontend from a Rails Engine?
I'm working on a Rails engine to extend and override the frontend of a Mastodon project. I've successfully integrated additional models and controllers into my engine, but I'm stuck on how to properly override and extend the Mastodon frontend (e.g., views, JavaScript, CSS).
Has anyone done this before or has experience with extending the Mastodon frontend using a Rails engine? I'm particularly interested in the best practices for overriding existing views, adding new ones, and customizing the JavaScript and CSS. Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
